# How to set version number in sbt when building & publishing akka-http

Tags: sbt, akka, version

I'm trying to experiment with a local copy of the `akka-http` library. I can publish it locally with `sbt publishLocal`, but I can't figure out how to change the version number. `build.sbt` contains an `organization` field but no simple `version` field - that seems to be generated from somewhere else and I can't figure out where. It's currently at `10.0.5`but grepping that string in the source doesn't turn up anything obvious.

Seems like a simple question, but where is version defined? Thanks.

(I'm asking this because `sbt` docs tell me I should name my local version something like `0.1-SNAPSHOT`. I assume there must be a simpler way to do this than by disabling the auto-generation logic and hardcoding it into `build.sbt`)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Akka-HTTP generates its version at run-time.

If you look at [`akka-http/akka-http-core/src/main/resources/reference.conf`](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/ba941e193624ae6d3f1d134d7584505a179a035e/akka-http-core/src/main/resources/reference.conf):

> Akka HTTP version, checked against the runtime version of Akka HTTP.
>   Loaded from generated conf file.

And then look at [`akka-http/project/Version.scala`](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/project/Version.scala):

```
/**
 * Generate version.conf and akka/Version.scala files based on the version setting.
 */
object Version {

  def versionSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = inConfig(Compile)(Seq(
    resourceGenerators += generateVersion(resourceManaged, _ / "akka-http-version.conf",
      """|akka.http.version = "%s"
         |""").taskValue,
    sourceGenerators += generateVersion(sourceManaged, _ / "akka" / "http" / "Version.scala",
      """|package akka.http
         |
         |import com.typesafe.config.Config
         |
         |object Version {
         |  val current: String = "%s"
         |  def check(config: Config): Unit = {
         |    val configVersion = config.getString("akka.http.version")
         |    if (configVersion != current) {
         |      throw new akka.ConfigurationException(
         |        "Akka JAR version [" + current + "] does not match the provided " +
         |          "config version [" + configVersion + "]")
         |    }
         |  }
         |}
         |""").taskValue
  ))

  def generateVersion(dir: SettingKey[File], locate: File => File, template: String) = Def.task[Seq[File]] {
    val file = locate(dir.value)
    val content = template.stripMargin.format(version.value)
    if (!file.exists || IO.read(file) != content) IO.write(file, content)
    Seq(file)
  }
}
```

I'm assuming after generating the current version you should see a `akka-http-version.conf` file somewhere in your filesystem.

Comment: Yes, it does generate an `akka-http-version.conf` file. And this file contains `akka.http.version = "10.0.5+35-d117b194+20170419-2350"`. But my question is how does it decide to put `10.0.5` there. In order to work on my own version of the library, SBT docs tell me to call my version something like `0.1 SNAPSHOT`. How can I do this? Do I need to rip apart the auto-generated stuff and put `version` into `build.sbt` by hand, or is there a better way?

Comment: What happens if you try to set `version in ThisBuild := 1.0` in your `build.sbt`?

Comment: Yes, that works - it changes the version to 1.0. But when I try putting `version in ThisBuild := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"` it won't compile. I thought I was supposed to use `SNAPSHOT` for local development, or is this not necessary?

Comment: @thnd Doesn't matter if you're doing local experiments.